# swift MapKit not showing annotation pins

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

I'm learning swift and trying to use SwiftyJson to parse a json file and add annotations in the map view but couldn't get the pins showed on the simulator. I have a warning in the debugging area says that Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4. My code is as below and I've checked some of the answers about this problem but still couldn't fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
        class StationsViewController: UIViewController {

    var stations = [Station]()
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self //as MKMapViewDelegate
        //mapView.showsUserLocation = YES
        fetchJsonData()
        mapView.addAnnotations(stations)
        }
    func fetchJsonData() {
        // Fetching client list.
        let api_json_url = URL(string:"https://feeds.divvybikes.com/stations/stations.json")
        // Create a URL request with the API address
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: api_json_url!)
        // Submit a request to get the JSON data
        //let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data,response,error in

            // if there is an error, print the error and do not continue
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to parse")
                return
            }

            // if there is no error, fetch the json formatted content
            else{
                    let json = JSON(data:data!)
                    if let stationJSONs = json["stationBeanList"].array {
                        for stationJSON in stationJSONs {
                            if let station = Station.from(json: stationJSON) {
                                self.stations.append(station)
                    }
                }
            }
        }// end if
    } // end getDataSession

    task.resume()
    } // end readJsonData function
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for stationJSON in stationJSONs {
    if let station = Station.from(json: stationJSON) {
        self.stations.append(station)

        let latitude = station["latitude"]
        let longitude = station["longitude"]

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude)
        annotation.coordinate = centerCoordinate
        annotation.title = "Pass Title here"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }  
}
```

**check this.**

Comment: WOW! It worked! Thank you soooooooo much! You are a life saver! I thought what I did in the viewdidload and in the class was enough to pass data...

Comment: Great answer, saved my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addAnnotation` in `fetchJsonData()`, because `fetchJsonData()` is executed asynchronously.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self //as MKMapViewDelegate
    //mapView.showsUserLocation = YES
    fetchJsonData()
}

func fetchJsonData() {
    // Fetching client list.
    let api_json_url = URL(string:"https://feeds.divvybikes.com/stations/stations.json")
    // Create a URL request with the API address
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: api_json_url!)
    // Submit a request to get the JSON data
    //let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data,response,error in

        // if there is an error, print the error and do not continue
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to parse")
            return
        }

            // if there is no error, fetch the json formatted content
        else{
            let json = JSON(data:data!)
            if let stationJSONs = json["stationBeanList"].array {
                for stationJSON in stationJSONs {
                    if let station = Station.from(json: stationJSON) {
                        self.stations.append(station)
                        mapView.addAnnotation(station)
                    }
                }
            }
        }// end if
    } // end getDataSession

    task.resume()
} // end readJsonData function
```